# Ruby Compass outputting backtrace in CSS

Tags: ruby, sass, backtrace

Compass is outputting a backtrace in the CSS instead of generating the CSS.  I have had the same results for Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux 12.0 I have tested this on Compass 0.12.2 AND 0.11.1 and I tested this on Ruby 1.9.3p385 AND 1.9.1P378.

My config.rb file:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
http_path = "/n4"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
# relative_assets = true
output_style = :compact #or :nested, :expanded, :compressed
line_comments = false    

 # Disable these for production (also when viewing in IE6; will cause unnecessary display errors)
 # sass_options = {:debug_info => true}
```

## The contents of the CSS file:

```
/*
Syntax error: Undefined mixin 'linear-gradient'.
    on line 305 of C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass, in `linear-gradient'
    from line 305 of C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass, in `button_style'
    from line 590 of C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass

Backtrace:
C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass:305:in `linear-gradient'
C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass:305:in `button_style'
C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass:590
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:251:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:266:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:266:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:266:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:119:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:266:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:68:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:261:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:107:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:119:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:106:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:318:in `visit_rule'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:107:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:119:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:106:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:126:in `visit_root'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:98:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-        0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:147:in `recompile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `run_callback'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/path.rb:55:in `callback_action'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/path.rb:35:in `update'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `block in modified'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in `refresh'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `loop'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fssm-0.2.10/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:87:in `perform'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Syntax error: Undefined mixin 'linear-gradient'.\A on line 305 of     C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass, in `linear-gradient'\A             from line 305 of C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass, in     `button_style'\A from line 590 of C:/Users/bens/workspace/n4e/src/main/webapp/sass/screen.sass"; }
```

Comment: I don't know why you were down voted but you should probably include the offending line from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Linear-gradient isn't a mixin in Compass.  It is a function that's intended to be used in combination with the `background` or `background-image` mixins.

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/

Comment: [linear-gradient](http://bourbon.io/docs/#linear-gradient) exists as a Bourbon mixin. You can use [bourbon-compass](https://github.com/jedfoster/bourbon-compass) to integrate Bourbon with Compass.

Answer (score -1):

You're seeing that message because you have an error in your SASS file. When there are errors, SASS will output the error, a back trace (as you've noticed) and a CSS rule prepending the error before the `<body>` tag.